# GetEnumerator() in the middle of a string

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a *very* long string, and would like to get an enumerator (for LINQ goodness) that begins in the middle of the string, at a given index. That is,

```
var longString = GetLongString();
var index = 99999;

// seems unnecessarily expensive to allocate a new string
var enumerator = longString.Substring(9999).GetEnumerator();

// Use LINQ.
enumerator.TakeWhile( /* ... */ );
```

is there a better (ie: cheaper/faster) way to do this?

Comment: I still wonder what benefit something like this would have over, say, Substring

Answer (score 9):

Consider [`Enumerable.Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
longString.Skip(9999).TakeWhile( /* ... */ );
```

However, keep in mind that as [Michael Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622569/3246555) wrote, `Skip` works in iterative way (strictly speaking it depends on implementation, but at least this is what you usually have, see e.g. [.NET Framework 4.6 Reference Sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,83ec6a20321060a1)). If it causes *measurable*<sup>1</sup> slowness in your case, look at Michael's extension method.

---

1. [D.Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth): "*premature optimization is the root of all evil* "

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Will utilize it as essentially a char array without re-allocating a new string.

Comment: @Tim It is indeed a typical way to ignore elements using Linq, but in may take `O(N)` instead of `O(1)` time.

Answer (score 5):

Using `longString.Skip(n)`, as in [AlexD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31621576/1127114), will make *n* calls to the underlying enumerator's MoveNext method to skip past all the characters you don't care about. For large values of *n*, you can improve performance by writing a custom iterator method:

```
public static IEnumerable<char> EnumerableSubstring(this string s, int startIndex)
{
    for (; startIndex < s.Length; startIndex++)
        yield return s[startIndex];
}
```

Sample usage:

```
longString.EnumerableSubstring(9999).TakeWhile( /* ... */ )
```